How to group Row with duplicate value in specific column by Combobox?
I want to group rows with duplicate values ​​in a specific column in a data table into a combo box and display them in a DataGridView.
However, when adding/deleting rows to the data grid view configured in this way, the function to delete from the linked data table was also required, and when selecting a combobox, there was a need to retrieve the value of the selected row among overlapping rows.
but, when I tried to create the function, an error occurred saying that a Combobox cannot be created in a bound view, so I could not create it.  In a view bound to a Datatable, rows with duplicate values ​​of a specific column (in the example, the value of the Context Column) are grouped into a Combobox (in the example, within the "standard" column), and then when the value within the ComboBox is selected, How do I select the value of the row that has that value?
private void TEST_PopulateDataGridView()
{
    try
    {
        dgv_target.DataSource = null;

        if (!dt_target.Rows.Count>1)
        {

            dgv_target.Columns.Clear();
            foreach (DataColumn _column in dt_target.Columns)
            {
                dgv_calculateCBS.Columns.Add(_column.ColumnName, _column.ColumnName);
            }
            // find duplidate row in "Context"column
            var _groupedRows = dt_target.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(row => row["Context"].ToString())
                .ToList();
            foreach (var _group in _groupedRows)
            {
                DataRow _firstRow = _group.First();
                DataGridViewRow _newRow = new DataGridViewRow();
                _newRow.CreateCells(dgv_target);
                if (_group.Count() > 1) //if exist duplicate
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn column in dgv_target.Columns)
                    {
                        //make combobox cell in "standard" column
                        if (column.ColumnName == "standard")
                        {
                            DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
                            var distinctValues = _group.Select(row => row[column.ColumnName].ToString()).ToArray();
                            comboBoxCell.Items.AddRange(distinctValues);
                            comboBoxCell.Value = distinctValues.First();
                            _newRow.Cells[dt_target.Columns.IndexOf(column)] = comboBoxCell;
                        }
                        else
                        { _newRow.Cells[dt_target.Columns.IndexOf(column)].Value = firstRow[column]; }
                    }
                    _newRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PaleVioletRed;
                }
                //not duplicate row
                else
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn column in dt_totalCBSSum.Columns)
                    {
                        _newRow.Cells[dt_totalCBSSum.Columns.IndexOf(column)].Value = firstRow[column];
                    }
                }
                dgv_target.Rows.Add(_newRow);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}


